# Exit system call causes process to core dump

Tags: c++, exit

We were using exit(rc) in our C program. However, it is dumping core.

Attaching to dbx produced below O/P

```
warning: Unable to access address 0xf07519a4 from core
pthdb_session.c, 546: 1 PTHDB_CALLBACK (callback failed)
pthreaded.c, 1986: PTHDB_CALLBACK (callback failed)
Segmentation fault in Block_pool::~Block_pool() at line 32 in file ""
could not read "Pool.C"
(dbx) where
warning: Unable to access address 0xf07519a4 from core
pthdb_session.c, 546: 1 PTHDB_CALLBACK (callback failed)
pthreaded.c, 1986: PTHDB_CALLBACK (callback failed)
Block_pool::~Block_pool()(0xe9fb0, 0x0), line 32 in "Pool.C"
StringList_Init::~StringList_Init()() at 0x10169f0c
vxIpcChannel._::__srterm() at 0x101690d8
exit(??) at 0xd01835f0
```

Do we know some reasons why exit system call fails??

Comment: Without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to answer...

Comment: It's hard to tell what's causing your program to crash when you don't include the program? However it's likely that a thread within it is still executing and referencing memory that is free'd or destroy'd by the thread that calls exit(...)

Comment: BTW seems to me something allocated dynamically fails..

Comment: The stack trace pretty clearly indicates that this is a C++ program, not a C program.  These are different languages, and the differences between them may be especially relevant to this particular behavior.  (Tags edited.)